# stellar js initialise with jquery only

Tags: jquery, stellar.js

stellar js requires following data attribute to element like:

```
    <div data-stellar-ratio="2"></div>
```

However I cannot use inline html on this particular site so I'd need to use only jquery.

I tried to add data attribute with jquery but it does not seem to work. Anyone have idea why?

```
    $(window).stellar(); 
    $('.gallery.home .image:nth-child(2)').data('stellar-ratio', '2');
```

Comment: show your html.... might be problem with the selector otherwise should work....or even may be you should wrap your code within the document.ready function....

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your stellar() method :

```
$('.gallery.home .image:nth-child(2)').data('stellar-ratio', '2');
$(window).stellar(); //after data-attribute is set...
```

Comment: thank you i tried that too but it did not work out :( and yes i have everything inside doc ready

Answer (score 0):

doh!

```
$('.gallery.home .kuva:nth-child(2)').attr('data-stellar-ratio', '2');
```